# How to add information in child rows with Child Rows (Datatables)

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

I am loading information in a table using Datatables, in this table I would like to load some information in the parent row and other information in the child row using the [Child Rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) API , to display the data I use AJAX like this:

```
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format(d) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>Invoice Date</td>' +
        '<td>' + d.InvoiceDate + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +       
        '</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#example').dataTable( {
         "ajax": {
             "type": 'POST',
             "url" : './utileria.php',  
             "dataType": 'JSON',             
             "cache": false,
             "data": {
                 'param' : 1,               
             },
         },
         columns: [
             {
                 "className":      'details-control',
                 "orderable":      false,
                 "data":           null,
                 "defaultContent": ''
             },
             { "data" : "PurchaseOrder" },             
         ],
         "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } )
    
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(format(row.data())).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });
});
```

For my server part I use PHP and this is how I loop through my table.

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $param = $_POST['param'];   
    switch($param) {
        case '1': //Consulta
                $query = array();
                include './db/conectar.php';
                $sql = "select PURCHID as 'PurchaseOrder',
                INVOICEDATE as 'InvoiceDate'
                FROM PP_FACTURAS F";
                $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
                if ( $stmt === false) {
                    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
                }   
                while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt) ) {
                    //print_r($row);
                    $record = array(
                       "PurchaseOrder"    => $row['PurchaseOrder'], 
                       "InvoiceDate"   => $row['InvoiceDate']       
                    );
                    array_push($query, $record);
                }               
                sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);       
                sqlsrv_close($conn);
                $json = array(
                    "success"=> count($query) > 0 ? true : false,
                    "data"=>$query
                );

                echo json_encode($json);
            break;
    
  }
?>
```

Here comes the interesting thing, currently I can show the **PurchaseOrder** field in my parent row but I would like my daughter row to show the **InvoiceDate** field , to explain a little more detail what I mean with parent row and child row I leave the example image.

[image]

In words more word less, I would like the child row to show the result of the InvoiceDate field when expanding the row.

**Update:**

According to some of the comments try adding `console.log(d);` to my function but I do not get any message in console.

```
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format(d) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    console.log(d);
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>Invoice Date</td>' +
        '<td>' + d.InvoiceDate + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '</table>';
        
}
```

Comment: check this other related question  [linkl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47311267/adding-detailed-information-child-rows-to-some-entries-in-datatables)

Comment: @Jatniel The link that you share with me is information from a JSON file in this case I am using a query to BD

Comment: hi, ok I'm not giving you the exact answer, maybe I could help you.

Comment: @Jatniel I had reviewed the example if it solved my problem but I realized that it does not do it with BD

Comment: Can you clarify (1) what specific problem you are facing, or what specific error(s) you may be seeing in the console? And (2) what are the contents of `d` in your `format(d)` function?

Comment: @andrewjames I'm not really facing a problem as such in fact in the console I don't get any error, here the only problem is that the `InvoiceDate` field is not displayed in the child rows and regarding the contents of d in the format function I have no idea, I just took it from the documentation provided by [Datatables.net](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)

Comment: You can add [logging statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) to your code - for example, to show what `d` contains: `console.log( d );`. Without more information, this is guesswork on my part - and therefore it will probably not be so helpful to you. Ideally, we need a [mre] (as is often mentioned in this site, because it is usually very helpful).

Comment: @andrewjames Add `console.log(d);` to my code but I did not get anything in console, I attach update in the question.

Comment: OK - thank you for the updates - much appreciated. This is all guesswork on my part, because there is no [mre]. But the lack of any output from that console statement tells me that the event listener for opening and closing the details row is probably not set up correctly (otherwise it would call the `format` function with valid data). That is all I can really tell you, from the information provided.